# Three numbers which are co-primes of each other such that the product of the first $2$ is $551$ and that of the last $2$ is 1073. Find the $3$ numbers

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

If we take a,b, and c as the three numbers then, I know the answer is got by using the fact that b will be the common factor of $551$ and $1073$. But what I don't understand is why is b taken as the gcd of $551$ and $1073$ as it can easily be just any of the common factors of those two numbers.

Comment: @dxiv Yup. But why should that number be taken as the gcd at all?? Where is it told it will be the gcd as it could be just any common factor of 551  and 1073.

Comment: @how did you come to that conclusion just by looking at the question? that there are just two common factors

Comment: `why is b taken as the gcd` Because if $b$ were a proper factor of the $\gcd$ then it would follow that $a$ and $c$ are not coprime.

Comment: Denote $A=ab$, $B=bc$, then: if assume that $GCD(A,B) = b g\;$ ($g> 1)$, then $A=\alpha\cdot b g, B=\beta \cdot b g$, where $GCD(\alpha,\beta)=1$; hence $a=\alpha g$, $b=\beta  g$. So $GCD(a,b)=g>1$ ($a$ and $b$ aren't co-prime).

Comment: @Oleg567 If a,b,c are co-prime does that make a and b also to be co-primes? and so is b and c and a and c to be coprime?

Comment: I was just failing with this one fact that Every common divisor of two integers divides their greatest common divisor.!!

Comment: @GRANZER `does that make a and b also to be co-primes` The title of your question says "*co-primes* ***of each other***". This would normally read as "***mutually*** co-prime", meaning that each pair of numbers is co-prime i.e. $\gcd(a,b)$ $=\gcd(b,c)$ $=\gcd(c,a)$ $=1$.

Comment: @dxiv Of course!! Thank you.

Comment: @Oleg567 Did you mean $c= beta.g$ and $GCD(a,c)=g>1$?

Comment: @GRANZER: oops, yes, sure; thanks for correction! it should be like this: $A=ab, C=bc$, $GCD(A,C)=bg$; $A=\alpha\cdot bg, C=\gamma \cdot bg$, hence ... $a=\alpha g$, $c=\gamma g$, so $GCD(a,c)=g>1$. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming $a,b,c$ are all positive.

$$ab=551$$
$$bc=1073$$

$b$ clearly is a common divisor.

Suppose it is not the greatest common divisor, then $a$ and $c$ would share some common factors that are bigger than $1$ which contradicts to the fact that they are coprime.

Comment: I am sorry but I think I am missing some crucial point of knowledge that is making me not grasp the answer. If b is not the gcd, how would that make a and c have factors bigger than 1? Also, a,b, and c are together suppose to be coprime so that doesn't have to mean a and c should also be co-primes

Comment: I was just failing with this one fact that Every common divisor of two integers divides their greatest common divisor.

Comment: Let $s$ be a common divisor of $a$ and $b$ and $d$ be the largest common divisor of $a$ and $b$. By Bezout's identity there exists $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $d=xa+yb$, since $s$ divides $a$ and $b$, it divides $xa+yb$ and it divides $d$.

Comment: If $b$ is not the gcd then the gcd must have some factors that don't come from $b$.  Where do they come from if they don't come from the $b $?  They can't come from $a$ or $c $.  What's left?  They can't come from anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

If $a,b,c $ are the numbers then $ab $ and $bc $ are the products.  Those have $b $ as a common factor. But $a$ and $c $ are relatively prime and have no factors in common.  So $ab$ and $bc$ can't have any factors in common that aren't a factor of $b $.

So $b$ is the greatest common factor of $ab $ and $bc $.  So we can find $b $.  Just divide $ab$ and $bc $ by $b$ to get $a $ and $c $.